# Trying to get concated primary keys using user defined variable

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an sql query that uses a group by. What I am trying to do, is introduce an extra column that would have the ids of all the columns in the result set concatenated with a `,` separator.
I have tried variations of the following:

```
set @vals='';  
select @vals:=concat(@vals,',',id),id,payment_num, sum(amount) from payments  
group by id,payment_num,  
having processed > 0;
```

I keep getting `null` in the first column. I tried `set @vals:=' '` i.e. with space but it fails as well.
What am I doing wrong.
My intention is to get the ids of all the result set returned as comma separated.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `group_concat()` with a subquery.  It is designed for this purpose:

```
select id, payment_num, sum(amount),
       (select group_concat(id) from payments where processed > 0) as ids
from payments  
where processed > 0
group by id, payment_num;
```

I must say, though, that this is an unusual request.  Why would you want the ids listed separated only each row, along with a column containing the complete list?

EDIT:

Your comment is wrong.  To do what you want, you need to do something like this:

```
select id, payment_num, sum(amount),
       (select group_concat(id) from payments having sum(processed > 0) = count(*)) as ids
from payments  
group by id, payment_num
having sum(processed > 0) = count(*);
```

Your version chooses the value of `processed` from an arbitrary row and uses that for the comparison.  My first version will have any group that has `processed > 0`.  This version requires that all the rows have `processed > 0`.  You can get the same effect using one of the following:

```
having min(processed > 0) > 0;
having min(processed > 0) = 1;
having min(processed > 0);
having max(processed <= 0) = 0;
```

I think the version with `count(*)` is the easiest to read.

EDIT II:

To fix the problem of getting the ids only from the groups where everything is processed.  So, basically introduce the original query as a subquery:

```
select id, payment_num, sum(amount),
       (select group_concat(id)
        from (select id, payment_num
              from payments
              group by id, payment_num
              having sum(processed > 0) = count(*)
             ) idpn
       ) as ids
from payments  
group by id, payment_num
having sum(processed > 0) = count(*);
```

This is yucky, but as I ask in the first version of the answer, putting the list of ids on each row seems like an unusual need given that you have a separate row for each id.  Also, you might get duplicates, so you would want `group_concat(distinct id)` to remove them.

Also, most other databases support the `with` statement, which would much simplify the query.

Comment: But this is not equivalent to my query.I have a series of rows in the table and I want to collect only the groups which have **all** the processed marked greater than 0.Using the `WHERE` results in getting groups having *any* row in the group having processed greater than 0). Right?

Comment: But I see you are keeping `select group_concat(id) from payments where processed > 0`. Doesn't this query select different ids than the ones return by the result set since the condition `from payments where processed > 0` and `group by id, payment_num having num(processed > 0) = count(*);` are different?

Comment: Perhaps I am missing something:`select group_concat(id) from payments having sum(processed > 0) = count(*)) as ids` this needs grouping right?

Comment: `This is yucky` I agree that is why I asked about using the user defined variable in the OP.Wouldn't that be more efficient? But why I can not get it to work?

Comment: @Jim . . . Even if the user defined variable did work, it would cumulatively add ids on each row.  My suspicion is that it doesn't even do this because id is `NULL` on one of the first rows.

Comment: But `id` is the primary key.How can it be null?